# Using TimedRotatingFileHandler, how to name the first log file by the same convention as the rotations?

Tags: python, logging

I'm using the `logging` module python 3.4 to log performance over many days. I wanted to have it rotate so that everyday it creates and writes to a new log file with the date in the name. The `logging` module's `TimedRotatingFileHandler` handler does that well enough. However, say I put in a log filename 'FN.log' and I get:

```
FN.log
FN.log.2016.05.03
FN.log.2016.05.04
FN.log.2016.05.05
```

etc..

Is there a way to have the first file also include the date? I've also considered maybe immediately triggering a rotation on startup which should do the trick but I don't know how to do that yet.
Thanks!

PS: Ideally, if I happen to kill the app and restart it on the same day, it would continue writing in the same log file as the pre-existing one from that day (the one created by the rotation, for instance). However that last bit is optional: if it's too hard, I can always create a new log directory everytime I run the program.

Comment: Why? I consider it a feature that the current log always has the same name. That allows tools like [`multitail`](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) to be started once and kept running on *one* file. If the current file changed ever day, tools like this would have to be restarted every day. That's not useful.

Comment: Thanks to you and Vinay for clarifying that the file without a timestamp is the current file. I misunderstood what was happening.

Comment: So while there are use cases for a consistent name for the current file, there are also use cases for consistent naming from the point of creation. It's unfortunate that this post has failed to answer the actual question and instead has answered something else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not the first file - it's the current file being logged to. When rollover happens, the file `FN.log` gets renamed with a name containing a date, and a brand new `FN.log` file is opened and used for subsequent logs until the *next* rollover.

Comment: I believe so - "The system will save old log files by appending extensions to the filename. The extensions are date-and-time based, using the strftime format %Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S or a leading portion thereof, depending on the rollover interval."